# laravel 8x livewire give Undefined variable when livewire use

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, livewires

i'm confusing of this code. i dont know why this be error.
this is the livewire function :

```
public $members;

public function render()
{
    $this->members = "members";

    return view('livewire.members');
}
```

and the view :

```
<div>
    <h1>{{$members}}</h1>
</div>
```

but i got this error
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to define your variable before render.

```
public $members = 'members';

// or

public function mount()
{
    $this->members = "members";
}

public function render()
{
    $this->members = 'members';

    return view('livewire.members');
}
```

For Laravel. Pass your variable to the view.

```
public function render()
{
    $members = "members";
    // $this->members = "members";

    return view('livewire.members', ['members' => $members]);
    // return view('livewire.members', ['members' => $this->members]);
}
```

Comment: I would rather not pass it though the `view()`, and instead just use the public property.  https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/rendering-components

Comment: This is confusing.

Comment: thank you, i'm using tutorial on youtube. they are not give this way. thank you, i cant upvote you, because my reputation is 1

Comment: @qirel i'm using public property, but idont understand, why i got the errors when others work